# API to automatically upload apk to Google Play?

Tags: android, api, apk, publish, google-play

Is there any API or tool that enables me to automatically upload an APK to Google Play? I want to automatically publish customized apps to my account without any manual steps or graphical interface.

I searched around but could not find any API for doing this (only [android-publisher](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/v1/) but it doesn't support publishing, despite its name). Did anyone solve this already, seems like a basic feature?

Comment: I don't think there is any, but this is an interesting question

Comment: Times change - let the comment reflect that there IS now such an API - previous comments and answers are now out of date - correct answer is now from sharshi.

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52374171/1531054

Comment: For those who came here through a web search and just want an answer, offtopic or not: [Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/) is a tool that automates Play Store and App Store deployments.

Comment: There is one: https://github.com/codebysd/java-play-store-uploader

Comment: this is a good question. they souldnt have closed it. some moderators on this site are really dumb

Answer (score 66, accepted):

As of today there is a new official publishing API That allows you to upload to any channel (ie. alpha, beta...) or update title and description and more.

From the docs:

> - Uploading new versions of an app  Releasing apps, by assigning APKs to various Tracks (alpha, beta, staged rollout, or production)
> - Creating and modifying Google Play Store listings, including
> - localized text and graphics and multi-device screenshots

Look here for more info: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/

Comment: Note that the API is *only* for **already published apps** (that have at least one APK uploaded).

Comment: Authorisation with Google might be a trick. [Here's how](http://superuser.com/questions/606953/bash-oauth-2-0-jwt-script-for-server-to-google-server-applications) getting token via command line would look. P.S. The .p12 key mention there will not work until you convert it yo .pem with the command "openssl pkcs12 -in my_google_key.p12 -out my_google_key.pem -nodes -clcert"

Comment: UPDATE: Unfortunately as of today the main API command [Edits: insert](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/edits/insert) results in error messages of different kind with [no solutions yet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25054919/get-android-subscription-status-failed-with-403)

Comment: have a look with this gradle plugin - https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher

Comment: Does anyone know if the restriction of updating only preexistent apps still apply?

Comment: it looks like at this moment there is no way to upload new apks via AndroidPublisher API, only updates accepted?!

Comment: @RicardoPedroni Yes, the limitation still applies.

Comment: So it is still for already uploaded APKs?You cannot upload first version of an app through the API?

Comment: @Dokuzov yes only updates

Comment: Any API limit for access this google play store publish API? @sharshi

Comment: is this api are free to use?

Answer (score 23):

[gradle-play-publisher](https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher) is a Gradle plugin to upload your APK and app details to the Google Play Store.

I simply run `./gradlew publishApkRelease` from my terminal and it uploads the APK and the summary of recent changes., there are more task like this available.

It uses the [The Google Play Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/)

Comment: Hi, Im new to Gradle, gradle-play-publisher says "Once you have applied this plugin to your android application project you can configure it via the play block", Where I need to add play block?

Comment: In your `build.gradle` file

Comment: Could you please share your build file? Im constantly getting this exception "org.gradle.execution.TaskSelectionException: Task 'publishApkRelease' not found in root project"

Comment: I have posted my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31449533/task-publishapkrelease-not-found-in-root-project

Comment: not really active project anyhow

Comment: Why you say is not an active project?

Answer (score 20):

<strike>There is no official Google API for automating working with Google Play.</strike>  (This is NOT true after July 2014)

You can create a script that encapsulates a web browser and simulates user bevahiour: find HTML fields, enter info there, submitting the page, etc.

We are working on such open-source Python tool:
https://github.com/onepf/AppDF/tree/master/tools/uploader

Comment: This was true until late July 2014, when Google added a publishing API. See the answer from sharshi for more info.

Comment: This answer is now wrong.

Answer (score 4):

I answered this also on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427304/automatic-publish-beta-android-app-to-the-google-play-store/25353690#25353690), but I figured I'd add the same comment here.  Let me know if that's the wrong way to do this (duplicating answers).

I was able to create a gradle plugin that does the publishing to any track you wish for any flavor/variant you wish using the new Google Play Publishing APIs.

See the sources here: https://github.com/bluesliverx/savillians-gradle

I'm working on publishing this to maven central so it can be used in a build script, but for now you can grab the `android-publisher` subdirectory in the repo, put it in the root of your gradle build, and rename the folder to `buildSrc`. Use the following line in the `build.gradle` file for the android project you want to publish:

```
apply plugin: com.savillians.gradle.androidpublisher.AndroidPublisherPlugin
```

You can then set your publishing settings using an `androidPublisher` block in the build.gradle file.

```
android {
    ...
}
androidPublisher {
    applicationName = "Company-Name-Product-Name/1.0"
    packageName = "<package name>"
    serviceAccountEmail = "<service account email>"
    serviceAccountKeyFile = file('<p12 keyfile - NOT the json file>')
    track = "alpha" // default, don't need to specify
    variantName = "release" // default, don't need to specify
}
```

Make sure the service account you create has "release manager" permissions, download the p12 key file and put it in the project's directory. Then run this command:

```
gradle androidPublish
```

That will send it to Google Play using the credentials you specified. Good luck and let me know if you have questions since this is brand new.

Comment: please find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29816342/command-line-upload-of-apk-to-google-playstore  Does `gradle androidPublish` generate the signed apk and upload to playstore

Comment: Answered.  This plugin will do what you are looking for.

Comment: hi @bksaville is this plugin support for existing apps. Can't we use for newly  created apps.

Comment: I found that instead of "release manager" for the Roles when creating the service account I needed to instead: in the Role dropdown choose "Service Accounts" -> "Service Account User" and "Service Account Token Creator"