# did google play provide external interface to upload or update the apk?

Tags: android, google-play

I want to update the app through my own code.

Did Google Play  provide external interface to upload or update the app of android?

Comment: possible duplicate of [API to automatically upload apk to Google Play?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665518/api-to-automatically-upload-apk-to-google-play)

Answer (score 2):

It is now supported by the API :

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/