# Android developer console automatic updates of description and screenshots

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play

Is there any possibility of updating the description and changing the screenshots in the developer console programmatically? Every week I like to update the application with new screenshots and I have more than 500+ apps in play store like that. Every time, manually updating the description and screenshots for all the apps.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found [API to automatically upload apk to Google Play?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665518/api-to-automatically-upload-apk-to-google-play) , not sure if it's still work. Let us know if you find something, I'm also very interested by being able to do that.