# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. While uploading apk with Savillians-gradle and Triple-T gradle

Tags: android, gradle, google-play, app-store, android-gradle-plugin

I have try with [**savillians-gradle**](https://github.com/bluesliverx/savillians-gradle) and [**Triplet-T**](https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher) for publishing my apk to Play Store with gradle. However i got same issue in both way. I guess i might doing something wrong or there might be issue from both library. I don't know where is the problem.

I have configure everything as mention there i can able to build gradle successfully with both way.

Then i have try to upload apk file to play store but got error message.

- **Please checck my below implementation and output for savillians gradle**

I have execute gradle task as below:

> gradlew androidPublish

With above command i got error message like below:

> D:\Directory\myproject>gradlew AndroidPublish
>   :buildSrc:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
>   :buildSrc:compileGroovy
>   :buildSrc:processResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :buildSrc:classes
>   :buildSrc:jar
>   :buildSrc:assemble
>   :buildSrc:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
>   :buildSrc:compileTestGroovy UP-TO-DATE
>   :buildSrc:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :buildSrc:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
>   :buildSrc:test UP-TO-DATE
>   :buildSrc:check UP-TO-DATE
>   :buildSrc:build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Failed to notify task execution graph listener.

  > com.google.common.hash.HashCode.fromString(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/comm
  >   on/hash/HashCode;
  >   com.google.common.hash.HashCode.fromString(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/comm
  >   on/hash/HashCode;
  >   com.google.common.hash.HashCode.fromString(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/comm
  >   on/hash/HashCode;
  >   com.google.common.hash.HashCode.fromString(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/comm
  >   on/hash/HashCode;
  >   com.google.common.hash.HashCode.fromString(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/comm
  >   on/hash/HashCode;
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
  option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 23.185 secs

- **Please checck my below implementation and output for Triplet-T gradle**

I have execute gradle task as below:

> gradlew publishApkRelease

With above command i got error message like below:

> D:\Directory\myproject>gradlew publishApkRelease
>   :buildSrc:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
>   :buildSrc:compileGroovy
>   :buildSrc:processResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :buildSrc:classes
>   :buildSrc:jar
>   :buildSrc:assemble
>   :buildSrc:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
>   :buildSrc:compileTestGroovy UP-TO-DATE
>   :buildSrc:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :buildSrc:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
>   :buildSrc:test UP-TO-DATE
>   :buildSrc:check UP-TO-DATE
>   :buildSrc:build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Failed to notify task execution graph listener.

  > com.google.common.hash.HashCode.fromString(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/comm
  >   on/hash/HashCode;
  >   com.google.common.hash.HashCode.fromString(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/comm
  >   on/hash/HashCode;
  >   com.google.common.hash.HashCode.fromString(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/comm
  >   on/hash/HashCode;
  >   com.google.common.hash.HashCode.fromString(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/comm
  >   on/hash/HashCode;
  >   com.google.common.hash.HashCode.fromString(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/comm
  >   on/hash/HashCode;
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
  option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.9 secs

So, please help me for this issue. I need help to upload apk file to play store using gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That issue is resolved. I guess i have added the configuration and other task within wrong manner. So, because of that, it is first looking for the release apk file to upload even it is not build. Because of that I might got issue.

But, after configuring all with in separate tasks (First Build then release), its working great.

Below is my gradle.build file. It might help others if anyone getting same problem.

//-------------------------------------------------------------

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 19
        buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.your_package.your_project"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 20
            versionCode 10
            versionName "0.0.9"
        }
        signingConfigs {
            release {
               storeFile file("C:\PATH_FOR_KEYSTORE\YOUR_KEYSTORE.keystore")
               storePassword "KEYSTORE_PASSWORD"
               keyAlias "KEYSTORE_ALIAS"
               keyPassword "ALIAS_PASSWORD"
            }
       }
       buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   'proguard-rules.txt'
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
            debug {
            }
       }
       packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
       }

    }

    // For the TRIPLET gradle demo

    apply plugin: 'play'
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
           // ...
           classpath 'com.github.triplet.gradle:play-publisher:1.0.2'
           classpath 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
        }
    }

    play {
        serviceAccountEmail = 'randomNumber@developer.gserviceaccount.com'
        pk12File = file('D:\someDirectory\MyProject\number.p12')
        track = 'beta' // or 'beta' or 'alpha' or 'production'
    }

 dependencies {
   // some required dependencies for the project library
 }
```

Hope this will help others also and save their time when they got such issue.

Enjoy Coding... :)

Comment: Considering that you're having the same problem with both libraries (and maybe I'm a little biased since savillians-gradle is mine), I believe that the guava/hashcode problems are related to the code in your project and not to either deployment library.  That's just a guess, however, since I've never seen those errors nor had them reported by anyone else using the project.

Comment: @bksaville the error is not related to guava library. But if someone having same issue because of any reason then they can add guava library and try once. You have not updated the proper information on your github that's why users(developers) are not getting how to use it and implement it.

Comment: @bksaville please check here: https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher  The information should be updated in the readme file of the parent directory. It would be great if you can update same for your repository.

Comment: I moved the repository around a bit so that it's the only project in there (top level).  Let me know if you have any other issues.