# Get android subscription status, failed with 403

Tags: android, google-api, subscription, in-app

While trying to get android in-app subscription status (with expiry date), I get the following error message:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "androidpublisher",
    "reason": "projectNotLinked",
    "message": "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console."
 }
}
```

The URL is: https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/[packageName]/inapp/[productId]/purchases/[purchase_token]?access_token=[access_token]

It says the project id is not linked. I have done the following:

> ```
> 1. Create the project in Google Developer Console.
> 2. Turn on the Google Android Publisher API.
> 3. Link the project ID as mentioned in API access page (https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started)
> 4. Fill in the packageName, productId (from in app-purchase), purchase_token (from Android app)
> ```

Not sure why the error message appear as above. I have tried with the OAuth2 playground with no luck (https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)

Answer (score 15):

I spent some time on this but at the end the error message says all:
"[...] has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console".

I spent hours looking in the Google Developer Console, but the place where to link the project is in the Google **Play** Developer console.

Just go to Settings -> Api Access and you'll be able to link the project you created in the Google Developer Console.

Here is a working PHP solution to get the subscription status. You need to create a service account in the Google Developer Console -> 'your project' -> API & Auth -> Credential and download the Google API PHP Client from https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

```
    set_include_path("../src/" . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
    require_once 'Google/Client.php';
    require_once 'Google/Service/AndroidPublisher.php';

    $client_id = '';    //Your client id
    $service_account_name = '';  //Your service account email
    $key_file_location = ''; //Your p12 file (key.p12)

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName(""); //This is the name of the linked application
    $service = new Google_Service_AndroidPublisher($client);

    $key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
    $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $service_account_name,
        array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher'),
        $key
    );
    $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
    if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
      $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
    }        
    $apiKey = ""; //Your API key
    $client->setDeveloperKey($apiKey);

    $package_name = ""; //Your package name (com.example...)
    $subscriptionId = "";   //SKU of your subscription item

    //Token returned to the app after the purchase
    $token = "";

    $service = new Google_Service_AndroidPublisher($client);
    $results = $service->purchases_subscriptions->get($package_name,$subscriptionId,$token,array());

    print_r ($results); //This object has all the data about the subscription
    echo "expiration: " . $results->expiryTimeMillis;
    exit;
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved me a lot of trouble. Can't believe how difficult this is to set up!

Comment: Have you been able to confirm that with v2 api you can only fetch purchases list using service account?

Comment: Additional info: The Developer Console API project (and the oauth2 credentials) has to be created with the same Google account as used in Google Play Developer Console. Otherwise you cannot link a specific project from the Developer Console API.

Comment: How to obtain my p12 file (key.p12)?

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same issue. Seems the authentication has changed in the v2 api.

You can still use the old api endpoint (v1.1). it works fine for me.

`https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v1.1/applications/{packageName}/inapp/{productId}/purchases/{token}`

Comment: Hey are you sure your authenticating a user with the correct permissions?

Comment: 'package name" ,productID, but what is here the {token} from where i will get it

Answer (score 3):

It's 2019 and this problem still exists. However, I found on another answer somewhere that someone said you had to create a new product in your account after setting this app up... and *that* actually worked for me.

Comment: thanks for your hint to create a new product. In my case it was not necessary to create a new product, but to only update the product in the developer console.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of @FabrizioFarenga answer, I created this code of the latest update of `Google API PHP Client`

https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client version v2.10

```php
        $oauth_credentials = Storage::path('path/to/secret.json');

        $subscriptionId = "";
        $packageName = "";
        $purchaseToken = "";


        $client = new \Google\Client();
        $client->setAuthConfig($oauth_credentials);
        $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher");

        if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion();
        }

        if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
            $service = new \Google\Service\AndroidPublisher($client);
            $results = $service->purchases_subscriptions->get($packageName, $subscriptionId, $purchaseToken, []);
            return $results;
        }

        die('die---');
```

Also check those useful documentations:

### Example

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/main/examples/multi-api.php

### Google API Client Upgrade Guide

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/main/UPGRADING.md

Answer (score 1):

I used Fabrizio Farenga's code and the Google API code with good results. In addition, it's worth noting that the permission your service account needs to access this is just ***View financial reports***.