# Google Play Android Developer API not linked with Google Play Account

Tags: google-api, google-play

I try to check purchase status of in-App product via Google Play Android Developer API and it return error 403 with message "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console." But Google API project id was linked Google Play Developer API.
This error was apeared only in last week - before it's worked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get android subscription status, failed with 403](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25054919/get-android-subscription-status-failed-with-403)