# 403 error: The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console

Tags: android, google-api, google-play

I'm using v2 of the Google Play Developer Console account.

I go to the [online API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/androidpublisher/v2/androidpublisher.edits.insert) to make a new edit.

I type in my package name (com.companyname.appname) in the `packageName` field, hit "Execute," and get this `403` error in response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "androidpublisher",
    "reason": "projectNotLinked",
    "message": "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console."
 }
}
```

I actually do have my Google Play Developer API project linked:
[image]

Why does Google keep giving me this error?

Comment: I now use v2 perfectly, I got this error when I authenticated an account without the proper permissions.

Comment: Similar problem in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481207/why-getting-error-the-project-id-used-to-call-the-google-play-developer-api-has

Answer (score 2):

This may not be what the OP was looking for but i stumbled upon this when looking for answers to receiving the exact same error when using service accounts. In case it helps anyone else, make sure you are using the json key for a service account that belongs to the linked project.

I just came across this same issue, in my case I had three projects in Google Dev console and when switching between it and the Google Play Dev console I ended up in the wrong project on Google Dev side. After much confusion I went to the Google Dev console, made sure I was in the linked project, went to service accounts and generated a new json key for the service account, updated my script to use it, and now I'm receiving the correct responses from google.

The json key should start with the same project name you have linked in the Google Play Dev console. When using one from the wrong project I was getting the exact same response as in the question.