# "message": "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console."

Tags: google-api, google-api-client, google-play-developer-api, google-developers-console, google-console-developer

I am trying to use the following API to download reviews for Android Apps.
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/reviews

But it requires authentication. 
So I followed the instructions that were linked in the link above.

I was able to get an access token.

But I get the following response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "androidpublisher",
    "reason": "projectNotLinked",
    "message": "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console."
 }
}
```

I saw some other posts saying that you have to link it with the Google Play Developer Console. So I did that (see image below).

[[image: Google Play Console, Linked Project]]

But I am still getting this error. PLEASE help.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the issue? I have the same problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why getting error 'The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481207/why-getting-error-the-project-id-used-to-call-the-google-play-developer-api-has)

Comment: I have te same error. I need help!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This is not fresh in my mind. But the issue was that the developer account DO NOT allow you download the reviews for Apps that aren't published through your developer account. So you CAN'T download reviews for Apps you have not published yourself. There are some unofficial APIs that can download the reviews but they are limited (won't be able to download all the reviews).

Answer (score 14):

The simplest solution is to just create a new in app product on the Google Developer console. Any in app product would do, just create a new one. My gut feeling is that the new product triggers a cache invalidation on Google side which then refreshes the permissions. Yes, crazy but effective.

Comment: this is indeed the only thing that worked for me after trying everything else

Comment: Even this step is not working for me. Could someone provide some other troubleshooting steps.

Comment: You are my hero 

Answer (score 1):

The error says.. your project id has not been linked. I see you have two projects, one you can unlink and one you can link. Are you sure you are not switching them around?  Also, can you please show how youre using the token?

Comment: Yes, so I sent a GET request as follows:
https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/com.spotify.music/reviews?access_token=myAccessTokenThatIGot

Yes. I my project is linked, see image... I think that is what I am supposed to it...