# Project has not been linked in Google play developer console, error came while I called the Google Developer API

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-console, google-developers-console, google-play-developer-api

I have integrated Google In-App subscription in one of my apps. It was integrated successfully. But, one mistake I have made while making subscription plans without a linked project with Google Play Developer Console. I found the same issue's answer on stackoverflow and everyone said that first link your project and then start to create subscriptions plans. I created a few more plans after the project linked, but this issue yet not fix.

*Below, I have attached error snippets*

[image]

[image]

Here, I saw you exact steps that I have performed.

1. At first, we made two plans(in-app product, subscription) and then we linked the project through google play console.
2. When we hit the **[google play developers API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/inappproducts/get)**, we get **error 403, "Project Id not linked to google play"**.
3. After searching through StackOverflow, we got to know, first, **the project is to be linked and then the subscription plans are to be added.** So we made two more plans in the project after linking it.

However, **the error still persists.**

**Can you please help us with why this error is coming despite the project being linked and subscription plans made after linking that project?**

The below added are links that we refer for the solution. 
The API URL that we use: `Purchases.subscriptions: get and Inappproducts: get`

[image]

Also, here I have attached stackoverflow and GitHub links which have the answers on the same issue that I already tried:

[Error: 'The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481207/error-the-project-id-used-to-call-the-google-play-developer-api-has-not-been-l)

["message": "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342740/message-the-project-id-used-to-call-the-google-play-developer-api-has-not-be)

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/1529

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52742878/9186913 i think this will work.

Comment: @rajkavadia

I already tried this solution

Comment: @FenilPatel can you verify if the name of google cloud project you are using is "Pmapps" and not anything else?