# Google Play Review API

Tags: google-api, google-play-services

I am trying to do a POC using GOOGLE Play review API, to get the reviews of an Application available in Playstore. I tried Getting the Reviews for Samsung App, but the API failed with below Error

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "androidpublisher",
                "reason": "projectNotLinked",
                "message": "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console."
            }
        ],
        "code": 403,
        "message": "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console."
    }
}
```

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why getting error 'The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481207/why-getting-error-the-project-id-used-to-call-the-google-play-developer-api-has)

Comment: That question doesn't help many of the front cases that hear come up with this.