# Service account and Google Play Developper API

Tags: google-api-java-client

I try to validate my mobile users purchases on the server, as described in https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_best_practices

I'm facing the infamous error "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console."

After lots of digging on SO, Google, ... and still having the problem, I ask for your help.

So here is my setup :

1. The service account is configured in my G play console :
   [image: G play console]
2. The service account has permission :
   [image]
3. I've downloaded a JSON key from the Google Developers Console
4. I'm running the following Kotlin code

Code :

```
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.25.0'
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-androidpublisher:v3-rev30-1.25.0'


val httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport()
val jsonFactory = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance()
val applicationName = "MYAPP"
val packageName = "my.package"
val json = "copy/paste json key here"
val credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(StringInputStream(json), httpTransport, jsonFactory)
      .createScoped(listOf((AndroidPublisherScopes.ANDROIDPUBLISHER)))
val publisher = AndroidPublisher.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
      .setApplicationName(applicationName)
      .build()

val productId = "product_id"
val userPurchaseToken = "a_token"
val get = publisher.purchases()
        .products()
        .get(packageName, productId, userPurchaseToken)
val purchase = get.execute()
Logger.getLogger("Payment user").info("Found google purchase item ${purchase.toPrettyString()}")
```

And then I get the exception

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code": 403,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "androidpublisher",
      "message": "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console.",
      "reason": "projectNotLinked"
    }
  ],
  "message": "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console."
}

at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:150)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1067)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
```

Note that I've waited 24 hours and still have the same error.

5. the very strange thing is that I manage to list the APKs with the code sample at https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-publisher-api/blob/master/v3/java/src/com/google/play/developerapi/samples/ListApks.java

I'm totally lost here ...

Why do my key works for listing the APKs but does not work to validate a purchase ?

EDIT : added step 5

Comment: Hello, which json i should put here? "val json = "copy/paste json key here"

Answer (score 0):

To me this part helped.

```
If you get the same error again, maybe is because you have configured and 
purchased products in your console before linking the project.

To solve it, simply add new product in your app.
```

From this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25655897/5169529