# In App Update not showing Update Screen untill I open playstore and see update button in Android

Tags: android, in-app-update

I implement In-App Update feature in my android application but it not working untill i go to playstore app and view update button.
Please suggest me some solution.
Thanks

```
   public void ImmidateUpdate()
    {

        AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(getActivity());

// Returns an intent object that you use to check for an update.
        Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();

// Checks that the platform will allow the specified type of update.
        appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo -> {
            if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE)
            {
                if(appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE))
                {
                    try {
                        appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                                // Pass the intent that is returned by 'getAppUpdateInfo()'.
                                appUpdateInfo,
                                // Or 'AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE' for flexible updates.
                                AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,
                                // The current activity making the update request.
                                getActivity(),
                                // Include a request code to later monitor this update request.
                                1210);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the priority using the Google Play Developer API as described in the Play Developer API documentation. In-app update priority should be specified in the Edit.tracks resource passed in the Edit.tracks: update method.

please refer to the [documntation](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates/kotlin-java#java)

Comment: How to set this one.

{
  "releases": [{
      "versionCodes": ["88"],
      "inAppUpdatePriority": 5,
      "status": "completed"
  }]
}

Comment: you need to use Play Developer API https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/edits

Comment: How i authenticate my request.
I am getting this response

{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}

Comment: I am Using this one
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/edits.tracks/update

Comment: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481207/error-the-project-id-used-to-call-the-google-play-developer-api-has-not-been-l