# I already linked API still getting Exception: "The project id used to call the GP Dev API has not been linked in the GP Dev Console."

Tags: google-play-console, http-status-code-403, google-apis-explorer, google-play-developer-api

Exception in Google Play Developer:

Team, I have already linked API access. Please refer to the attachment. I'm the owner of this app.

[image]

However, I still getting this exception - when calling this API to collect the google play reviews `https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/com.dhanamanikandan.dhanarandomizer/reviews?access_token=<token>`

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

Please note it was working until March 2021. I just noticed today and got this error.

Note: I have already reviewed these questions but it didn't help me!

[Error: 'The project id used to call the Google Play Developer API has not been linked in the Google Play Developer Console.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25481207/error-the-project-id-used-to-call-the-google-play-developer-api-has-not-been-l)

[Get android subscription status, failed with 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25054919/get-android-subscription-status-failed-with-403)

Comment: Hi @Dhana,
did you get the solution? please let me know if you found it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the publisher made for web servers, you **have to** access via Web Application credentials. Follow these steps to get access token and use it for api calls via postman if you want. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53529534/1977021

Comment: Hey, do You maybe know that https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/edits.tracks/get should works from Google Api Explorer ? Did You maybe ever try to use it ?

Comment: Of course i tried. It was the first thing i try. It is not working.