# Command line upload of apk to google playstore

Tags: bash, api, google-play, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I am using TeamCity as my CI server. I want to add a build step such that the generated signed apk of an android project should get uploaded to google playstore automatically. Are there any API available for the same. Is there any terminal commands available for the same.

I referred [API to automatically upload apk to Google Play?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665518/api-to-automatically-upload-apk-to-google-play) but found no recent activity on uploading via API or command line. Please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

The [Gradle Android Publisher plugin](https://github.com/bluesliverx/gradle-android-publisher) does exactly that, as explained in the question you referred to.  Fair warning: I created the plugin, so there may be others out there that do something similar.  When I created it, nothing else was available.

`gradle androidPublish` will first run the gradle android build process to build a release and signed (if you configured signing) APK, then it will take care of uploading that to google play based on your configuration.

See the other question or the link above for information on how to configure the plugin.