# Upload initial APK to Google Play Developer Console without using the web interface

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-developer-api

I want to Upload initial APK to Google Play Developer console without using the web interface, with plugin or library.

We can upload update APK (NOT initial APK) with library or plugin like [gradle-play-publisher](https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher), [fastlane/supply](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/supply), etc.

But [gradle-play-publisher](https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher) says at README.

> 1. Upload the first version of your APK using the web interface.

And [fastlane/supply](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/supply) has next issue.

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/3628#issuecomment-194089769

And This Question [[API to automatically upload apk to Google Play?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665518/api-to-automatically-upload-apk-to-google-play)] answers say that there is no way to upload initial apk.

Is there the way to upload initial APK to Google Play Developer Console without using the web interface.

Need to use headless browser?